# Как превратить строку(char) в число (int либо в double)

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь из строки

```
char peremen_t[255];
```

В ней лежат числа через пробел.

```
qDebug()<<"peremen_t " << peremen_t;
```

Вот что в ней ( peremen_t ) переменной лежит

```
peremen_t 1 26 48 1 48000 0.1
```

Поиск

```
 int tex_massiw_per[100]; // массив переменный куда буду скидывать переменные(по одной)
memset(tex_massiw_per, 0, sizeof(char)*255); // обнуляем массив состоящий из 255 элементов
int texn_per_nach =0; // технисечкая переменная начало
int texn_per_kon =0;  // техническая переменная конец
int texn_per_f =0;    // техническая переменная связанная тс ЭФФФФ
int s4et4ik_per_nach = 0; // счетчик который управляет этим дерьмом
int wihid = 0;
for (size_t d=0;d<sizeof(peremen_t)/sizeof(*peremen_t);d++)
{
    if (s4et4ik_per_nach == 0)
    {
        texn_per_nach = d;
        s4et4ik_per_nach = 1;
    }
    if (peremen_t[d] == ' ')
    {
        wihid= wihid +1;
        texn_per_kon = d;
        s4et4ik_per_nach =0;
        //-----
        int schet=0;
        //присвоение массиву переменной
        for (int g = texn_per_nach-1; g<texn_per_kon-1;g++)
        {
            tex_massiw_per[schet] = peremen_t[g];
            schet = schet+1;
            qDebug() << "tex_massiw_per[schet ="<< schet <<"]: " << tex_massiw_per[schet];
        }
        if(wihid == 6)
        {
            qDebug() << "break";
            break;
        }
    }
}
qDebug() <<"peremen_t[0]" << peremen_t[0] <<"peremen_t[2],peremen_t[3]" << peremen_t[2] << peremen_t[3];
qDebug() <<"peremen_t[5],peremen_t[6]" << peremen_t[5] << peremen_t[6];
qDebug() <<"peremen_t[8],peremen_t[9]" << peremen_t[8] << peremen_t[9];
qDebug() <<"peremen_t[11]" << peremen_t[11];
qDebug() <<"peremen_t " << peremen_t ;
```

Вот результат

```
peremen_t  1 26 48 1 48000 0.1  
tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 2 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  50 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 2 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  52 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  52 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 2 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 3 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 4 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 5 ]:  0 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  52 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 2 ]:  56 
tex_massiw_per[schet = 3 ]:  48 
break 
peremen_t[0] 1 peremen_t[2],peremen_t[3] 2 6 
peremen_t[5],peremen_t[6] 4 8 
peremen_t[8],peremen_t[9] 1   
peremen_t[11] 8 
peremen_t  1 26 48 1 48000 0.1
```

Считает компютер верно 6 чисел он заметил . Но вот результаты , даже те которые выпали  `( tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  52 tex_massiw_per[schet = 1 ]:  52` ) у меня таких даже НЕТ  .

Comment: есть стандартные **atoi** и **atof**, по сложнее **sscanf** (mscrt)

Comment: а задача в чем??

Comment: Вначале не запутывайте а правильно введите числа. Введите и сразу на экран. Когда ввод нормально - тогда можно делать дальше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QVector<double> charToDouble(const char *_input)
{
    QVector<double> outputVec;

    QStringList strVec = QString(_input).split(" ");
    for(int i = 0 ; i < strVec.size(); i++)
    {
        outputVec.push_back(strVec.at(i).toDouble());
    }

    return outputVec;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char var[255] = "1 26 48 1 48000 0.1";

    QVector<double> vec = charToDouble(var);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        qDebug() << vec[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: работаю в Qt 4.8 Могу сказать что этот код не работает (по крайней мере у меня)

Comment: @timob256 что значит "не работает"? не компилируется или результат не такой как ожидаете?

Comment: "QVector<double> charToDouble(const char *_input)
    { " тут создается класс а у меня так нельзя (либо я так просто не знаю как сделать )

Comment: C:\Works\res_glsso1\mainwindow.cpp:1192: ошибка: C3861: 'charToDouble': identifier not found

Comment: @timob256 у Вас неверная организация кода. выложите полный перечень файлов main.cpp, mainwindow.h, mainwindow.cpp

Comment: вы абсолютно правы , создал пустой консольный проект , все заработало . Буду пытаться организовать правильно код :3 Спасибо @Александр

Comment: Все работает :3

Answer (score 1):

А не проще типа

```
istrstream in(peremen_t);
...
double x;
while(in >> x)
{
    // Делать с x что надо
}
```

Да и сохранять в векторе?

Вот рабочий код:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char * peremen_t = "1 26 48 1 48000 0.1";
    istrstream in(peremen_t);
    vector<double>per;
    double x;
    while(in >> x) per.push_back(x);

    for(auto y: per) cout << y << endl;

}
```

Comment: у меня нету istrstream  , работаю в Qt 4.8 . Перейти на более новую версию увы  не могу .

Comment: istrstream - это стандартный поток C++, к Qt отношения не имеющий...

Comment: #include <istrstream.h>  либо #include <istrstream> . Зеленая волнистое подчеркивание и выпрыгивает маленькая надпись " strstream : Нет такого файла или каталога ."

Comment: Зачем же Вы рекомендуете устаревшие классы? Надо бы заменить на `stringstream` и `<sstream>`.

Comment: @alexolut Я их так редко использую, что все время путаюсь, какие старые, а какие новые... Какую бы мнемонику придумать? :)